# How can I export txt with writeObject() to a path within a string?

Tags: java, export, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I have been trying to export with writeObject method but I have only achieved exporting a txt if I write literally the name (or path) of the file I want in the output directly when I call the ObjectOutputStream() method.
What I want is to call a method I have created that asks the user for the name of the file he wants to,then I concatenate it with the rest of the path were it should be located but it does´t work.

This is what I want to use:

```
ObjectOutputStream fpsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nombreArchivo()));
```

Intead of this that is the only way to make it work:

```
ObjectOutputStream fpsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("NameOfTheFileOrCompletePath.txt"));
```

But I always receive the message of the catch block when executing:

When I execute the program and it tries to export the data I get the message of the catch block:

```
/*nombreArchivo is the String with the String returned by nombreArchivo.
```

Would be the same as writing FileOutputStream(nombreArchivo())); */
    try {
                ObjectOutputStream fpsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nombreArchivo)); //SERIA EL ARG NOMBREARCHIVO

```
            fpsalida.writeObject(listaprod); //Hay que pasarle el return de la lista de prod.CREAR LA FUNC RETORNAPROD
            System.out.println("\nExportado!\n");

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("No se ha podido exportar!\n");
        }

    return;
}
```

Here it is the part of nombreArchivo method that interests us:

```
System.out.println("\nWrite the name of the file you want: ");
    archivoSalida += sc.nextLine() + ".txt";
    System.out.println("==============================================\n");

    //archivoSalida is defined as a String
    return archivoSalida;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the nature of the problem? Are you getting an exception? Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: I have edited the original post with the error I get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was that the folder wasn´t created before.I thought the method if the directory doesn´t exist,it creates it.

Comment: FYI Javier, you can accept your own answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not getting an IOException when you hard-code the file name, your problem is the actual content of the string being returned by nombreArchivo().

To debug the specific nature of the problem, assign the returned string to a variable, and either log it, or print it out on System.err, so you can see what it really is:

```
String fileName = nombreArchivo();
System.err.println("str = \"" + str + \"");
ObjectOutputStream fpsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
```

The problem will likely be obvious when you look at the error stream. You should also consider logging or printing out the exception's stack trace in the catch block:

```
}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("No se ha podido exportar!\n");
}
```

I suspect fileName is either null, the empty string (""), or violates the OS's file name restrictions by (e.g.) containing illegal characters, such as line feeds.

**Update:** Based on your comment below, the problem is likely in how FileOutputStream calculates the file path. Try this instead, making sure that the String returned from nombreArchivo() is only the name of the file, without the directory path:

```
String fileName = nombreArchivo();
String filePath = "file://" + System.getProperty("user.home"); //* You may need to verify that file:// isn't already included in the user's home directory
URL url = new URL(filePath);
File directory = new File(url.toURI());
ObjectOutputStream fpsalida = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
FileOutputStream(new File(directory, fileName)));
```

**Explanation:** I learned this trick from the school of hard knocks. There are subtleties in how the file path gets calculated, and this is one way I've figured out of making it work in a platform-independent fashion.

Comment: That is what I have done. I assign the return value to a String and then it what I pass to the method between parenthesis.Also I have tried what you wrote and I get the following path in the String: "/Users/javserher/Desktop/tienda/Almacen/almacen.txt" so it is correct and the problem is not there

Answer (score 0):

The function `nombreArchivo` does seem to be returning an incorrect path since you are hardcoding the path instead. I would argue your hardcoded path is incorrect too, but need to see the exact error messaging to be able to tell.

I did test this example of `ObjectOutputStream` and seems to work fine.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class SandBox {

    // get absolute path from relative
    public static String getPath(String relativePath){
        return "/home/mack" + relativePath;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println("Write the name of the file you want: ");
        //extract filename from user
        String filename = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine() + ".txt";
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SandBox.getPath("/" + filename)));
            //write integer to stream
            stream.writeInt(12345);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SandBox.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to get the users home folder and then as the application should be in a defined folder in the desktop,the rest is the same for every user.That is why I use .getProperty ("user.home").So I can not use a defined String like yours ("/home/mack")